# DateFormat.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, datetime

Using this with some Kubernetes PODS and one of the pods out of the blue gives me this error. It seems to come from the call on line 6. Have not changed anything was just doing a deployment on gitlab and noticed this POD said `CrashLoopBackOff`.

/app/config/auth.js line 6

`var dateFormat = require('dateformat');`

My nodemodules folder has the latest dateFormat.js from package.json

So not sure what the problem is. Does someone know how to fix it?

````
var token=/d{1,4}|D{3,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|W{1,2}|[LlopSZN]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g;var timezone=/\b(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[A-Z][TC])(?:[-+]\d{4})?|((?:Australian )?(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time)\b/g;var timezoneClip=/[^-+\dA-Z]/g;export default function dateFormat(date,mask,utc,gmt){if(arguments.length===1&&typeof date==="string"&&!/\d/.test(date)){mask=date;date=undefined}date=date||date===0?date:new Date;if(!(date instanceof Date)){date=new Date(date)}if(isNaN(date)){throw TypeError("Invalid date")}mask=String(masks[mask]||mask||masks["default"]);var maskSlice=mask.slice(0,4);if(maskSlice==="UTC:"||maskSlice==="GMT:"){mask=mask.slice(4);utc=true;if(maskSlice==="GMT:"){gmt=true}}var _=function _(){return utc?"getUTC":"get"};var _d=function d(){return date[_()+"Date"]()};var D=function D(){return date[_()+"Day"]()};var _m=function m(){return date[_()+"Month"]()};var y=function y(){return date[_()+"FullYear"]

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/auth.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/passport.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)```
````

Comment: Please include more code...

Comment: Please format your code. The code in the OP is incomplete and contains syntax errors. See [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example.*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to fix it by downloading an older version of dateformat. Nothing wrong with my code on the question its a simple problem with the library not the code come on.

Comment: What version did you downgrade to?

Comment: try something 3.x or around there.

Comment: For me it was failing on `^5.0.3` and I downgraded to `^4.5.1` to make the error go away

Answer (score 1):

Here I could make it work by using another version of this package,was working in the version 4.6.3, so I did:

```
npm i dateformat@4.6.3
```